# Как сделать "неубиваемое" приложение в Android Enterprise?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-alarm-manager

Есть приложение **Device Owne**, в нем работает AlarmManager и каждые 10 минут отправляет сообщение на сервер, даже если приложение закрыть или перезагрузить устройство. Проблема в том, что если хорошенько нагрузить устройство и не трогать его через какое-то время аларм килится. Почитал про это, и вроде как такое происходит на китайских прошивках типа MIUI, EMUI, (тестирую на honor), говорят там стоит task manager который вырубает все что ему не нравится, а такие приложения как Whatsapp, Facebook там занесены в "белый список" и он их не трогает. Пробовал уже WorkManager, JobScheduler, DeviceAdminService, и вырубать оптимизацию батареи, ему вообще пофигу. Может есть у кого варианты, как сделать приложение **вообще не убиваемым** средствами android enterprise?

Comment: На тему AlarmManager: до андроид 8.0 сервис и notifications (неубиваемые натификации), с 8,0 Foreground Service и неубиваемые notifications. Можно здесь подсмотреть: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android